# Why would a find regex work, but a substitution regex fail?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to do a substitution (and have several others working in the same script), but it's failing even though what I'm looking for is there, and I know this for sure because a simple find regex succeeds.

```
print "$search : $replace \n";

if($output =~ /($search)/)
{
    print "found $1\n";
}

if($output =~ s/$search/$replace/)
{
    print "substituted\n";
}
```

I know from the first print statement that both variables contain expected values.

The "found" print statement prints the expected result.

The "substituted" print statement never prints, and the contents of $output are not altered by the substitution regex.

Why does the substitution not work even though the find does?

Comment: Can you give us values of $output, $search and $replace, so we could reproduce your case?

Comment: That's not going to be useful unless it reveals that `$search` uses `(?{ })` or `(??{ })`.

Comment: It's part of a larger transcript-filling thing. Some failing values are "BI-CH[\*]" for $search and "BIOS 320" for $replace. $output is the entire content of a large xml file containing all the data for a spreadsheet tracking completed and required courses. I will include a link to the file at the bottom of this comment. Some classes are labeled and others are more generic categories (like all the BI-CH\*). The hours/term/grade stuff is being replaced properly, but  the class name won't replace the generic one. https://www.dropbox.com/s/a9q1pdlbpkaq9qq/BiologyCurriculumWorksheetOriginal.xml

Comment: Being able to reproduce the problem is *always* critical.

Comment: @BlakeHood What `[*]` is doing in "BI-CH[*]"? Is it a special character? If not, do you properly escape it?

Comment: If `$search` is really equal to the string `BI-CH*` then you will certainly need to escape the special characters (e.g. with `\Q` ... `\E`). But that doesn't explain why the substitution is failing entirely. I would also be interested to see a complete script, including the values of `$search` and `$replace`, that fails to work in your environment.

Comment: @qwrrty, Again, the values of `$search` and `$replace` would be useless. (`$replace` doesn't even factor into the value returned by `s///`!) If he's got a working demonstration, there's no need for the value. If he doesn't have a working demonstration, the values of `$search` and `$replace` are not gonna help debug the issue. We'd need the Devel::Peek Dump of `$search`.

Answer (score 2):

It wouldn't. You probably have

```
if($output =~ /($search)/g)
```

---

If that's not the case, please provide an actual demonstration of the problem. Or if that's not possible, at least provide the output of the following before each `if`.

```
use Devel::Peek;
Dump($output);
Dump($search);
```

Wouldn't hurt to provide the output of `perl -V` (uppercase `V`) too.